# Is it possible too get name and email from the same people picker field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, people-picker

So I have a list where I've got a couple of fields in a content type such as "name , country currentclient is"

Name field is a people picker

Country is mang Metadata

currentClient is mang metadata

This is all displayed in a custom display template using content search but my problem is that I want to show Full name and email from the same list without having to input the name 2 times to show it.

So is there a way to get both the name and email from the same people picker? or copy one people picker field to another?

Comment: Are you using REST?<br/>
Check out this link:<br/>
[SharePoint 2013: Get User Details from Person or Group field using REST API](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31210.sharepoint-2013-get-user-details-from-person-or-group-field-using-rest-api.aspx)